The Methods which are auto selected under Filters on API page, are these counting as Scopes?
The scopes listed on your OAuth consent screen are different from the scopes requested in your Cloud Console submission.
Is there a difference between the scopes selected in app verification versus "Methods" on the API page?
"Methods" look like sub-methods of the parent level Scope, but contains irrelevant uses I won't be needing such as "youtube.api.v3.V3DataVideoRatingService" -- should these more specific scopes be deselected in order to Narrow scopes for verification approval?
Methods under YouTube Data API v3

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
